# Why were R2-D2 and C3P0 being used by Rebels?

Tags: star-wars

Leia used R2-D2 and C3P0 to send a message to Obi-Wan Kenobi. R2-D2 was the primary astromech of Luke Skywalker. In *Star Wars: Rebels*, Bail Organa used R2-D2 and C3P0 against the Empire. Both droids always danced in rebel base and traveled with our heroes.

All this is despite the fact that C3P0 was designed by the first hand of Emperor in his childhood, and R2-D2 was his primary astromech and a friend of his? Couldn't this increase the probability of identity sabotage? Other than that, why would you trust those droids which were so close to the enemy? And, why couldn't they buy or pick a new shiny latest astromech and translator droid?

Comment: Presumably because they've always been reliable. Also, Leia doesn't have huge luxury of time when it comes to choice.

Comment: @Kyle Actual spelling of C3P0 is with zero, not English alphabet O. Zero is generally pronounced such way.. MS Office two dot O.

Comment: 1) Is there any evidence that Leia knew anything about the droids and their past? 2) The droids didn't belong to Leia, they belonged to Captain Antilles. Is there any evidence that he wasn't the one who picked them to come on the mission? 3) Is there any evidence that Captain Antilles knew anything about the droids and their past?

Comment: Actually I think [Leia was being used by R2-D2](http://km-515.livejournal.com/746.html) more than the other way around.

Comment: 3P0's memory was wiped so any past association would be moot. It's possible that _if_ Vader captured him then he can use his intimate knowledge to pry Rebel secrets from his memory but he'd have to know that he was with the Rebels, know that he was the same droid _and_ be the one doing it (not some random engineer). Y'know, like in Bespin. There is a comic (I've never read) where Vader examines the deactivated, in-pieces 3P0 in Bespin, but that's now non-canon. I dunno why R2 wasn't wiped but to many they are just interchangeable machines and, as mentioned, it wasn't a deliberate move by Leia.

Comment: @phantom42 In Rebels Senator Organa is shown with the droids. Specifically R2D2* so they are "his" droids to begin with. ( as part of the new canon ) how Wedge gets his hands on them will be interesting to see.
---------
* We see at the end of an episode that Organa has sent R2D2 to Spy/record the crew (Droids in Distress)

Comment: “Both droids always danced in rebel base” — they *danced*?

Comment: @Cherubel Hm. At the very end of *RotS*, Organa sent them off with Raymus Antilles (setting up the link to "Captain Antilles" mentioned in *ANH*). It's possible that Organa kept ownership for some time.

Comment: You can turn this around.  Isn't it possible the droids that have intimate knowledge of first hand of the Emperor are a strategy asset??

Comment: @SachinShekhar wookiepedia disagrees

Comment: @OrangeDog Disagrees on what?

Comment: spelling of C-3PO

Answer (score 3):

Despite C-3PO being crafted by Darth Vader, something that may not even be known by Princess Leia and especially wouldn't be known by Luke, he is in all regards an average [protocol droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Protocol_droid).

[image]

While it's true this makes it easy to disguise another protocol droid as him for infiltration, there's no reason for the Empire to try anything like this - he's a single little-known protocol droid that hardly does anything significant to help the Rebel cause.  It'd be much easier to plant an organic spy, who would be able to adjust to the situation and wouldn't be subject to repair jobs by the rebels that might reveal his nature as a spy.

R2-D2, despite being a remarkable little droid, is also a [factory model](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-series_astromech_droid), and despite carrying valuable information, isn't seen as much more than a piece of machinery by the imperial troops.

Couple that with the fact that they're always paired with Luke Skywalker, the irrefutable hero of the first Death Star run, and Princess Leia the once-princess of an entire planet, and you have two droids who are not much trouble to keep around, with two people who very much have the pull to keep them from being taken away.

As for why Luke and Leia want them kept around...well, they did save their lives that one time in the trash compactor...

Comment: In regards to the spy thing, isn't there a droid assassin in the EU/Legends that was disguised as a C3P0-like protocol droid?

Comment: You probably mean [C-3PX](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/C-3PX). There's also the [BL-series Battle Legionnaire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/BL-series_Battle_Legionnaire).

Comment: Oh, and [this chap](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R-3PO). Just missed the editing window which I didn't know existed.

Comment: I think that C3PO has terror of erase memory for a reason.  I think he was erased at least once before and that R2 is the primary story-teller here.